# How can I parse a string representation of an array of array of doubles?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm passing a JSON object in C#.  The original object is an array of arrays of doubles, e.g.

```
var arrayObject = [[1.2,3,1,0],[2.3,1,0,9],[3,6.7,9,1]]
```

To pass between JavaScript and C# this has been converted to a JSON representation of an array of arrays:

```
string json = "[[1.2,3,1,0],[2.3,1,0,9],[3,6.7,9,1]]"
```

How can I parse this?  I want to do something like `JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<myObject>>(json)`, but this gives me an error that "Type 'myObject' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

There's not much structure here in terms of a JSON object...and all I really need to do is parse this out into a set of arrays. 
I've read a little about [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but I don't want to add unnecessary class libraries.  Is there a simple way to parse this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, deserialize it into something the serializer does understand - a `double[][]` - then you can convert it however you want:

```
string json = "[[1.2,3,1,0],[2.3,1,0,9],[3,6.7,9,1]]";
double[][] arrayOfArrays = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<double[][]>(json);
```

Assuming your `myObject` class looks something like:

```
class myObject {
    public double[] Arr { get;set; }
}
```

Then you could use LINQ to convert it to what you're looking for:

```
List<myObject> list = arrayOfArrays.Select(x => new myObject { Arr = x }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you---an elegant solution.